# Most Recent Date after Date

Tags: sql

I am working on a SQL query to extract patient data.  I have 3 tables. One contains unique records for patient data (ie: First Name, Last Name, Date of Birth...).  The second table is the Surgery table, that captures the date and results that the patient has surgery.  The third table is the investigations table, that captures the investigations done after surgery. The key in the Patient table is called HUN, and it links the Surgery and Investigation tables in a 1 to many relationship.

What I need to find out, is what the most recent date of the investigation is after each surgery. One patient can have multiple surgeries, and I need to know the most recent investigation date following each.

Here is my data (Note: this is fictional data). There are 2 surgery dates: May 11, 2005 and November 22, 2010.  Within these I need to know the most recent investigation date following the surgery date.  The result should be 2 records:

242424  11-May-05   2011-07-19

and...

242424  22-Nov-10   2011-02-07

```
HUN     Surgery Date Investigation Date    
242424  11-May-05   2005-01-22     
242424  11-May-05   2006-03-29     
242424  11-May-05   2007-03-05     
242424  11-May-05   2008-04-01     
242424  11-May-05   2009-06-04     
242424  11-May-05   2009-06-19     
242424  11-May-05   2010-05-21     
242424  11-May-05   2011-02-07     
242424  11-May-05   2011-02-15     
242424  11-May-05   2011-07-19     
242424  11-May-05   2012-06-12     
242424  11-May-05   2012-09-18     
242424  11-May-05   2013-04-04     
242424  11-May-05   2013-10-30     
242424  11-May-05   2014-10-07     
242424  11-May-05   2015-09-09     
242424  22-Nov-10   2005-01-22     
242424  22-Nov-10   2006-03-29     
242424  22-Nov-10   2007-03-05     
242424  22-Nov-10   2008-04-01     
242424  22-Nov-10   2009-06-04     
242424  22-Nov-10   2009-06-19     
242424  22-Nov-10   2010-05-21     
242424  22-Nov-10   2011-02-07     
242424  22-Nov-10   2011-02-15     
242424  22-Nov-10   2011-07-19     
242424  22-Nov-10   2012-06-12     
242424  22-Nov-10   2012-09-18     
242424  22-Nov-10   2013-04-04     
242424  22-Nov-10   2013-10-30     
242424  22-Nov-10   2014-10-07     
242424  22-Nov-10   2015-09-09
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `MIN()`.

Comment: Gordon, already tried that. Does not work. Just gives me the minimum date overall of the Investigation, not per Surgery.  Here is my result.  HUN       Surgery Date MinOfInvestigationDate
51704 11-May-05 2005-01-22
51704 22-Nov-10 2005-01-22
73403 15-Nov-68 1968-01-01
73403 11-Aug-95 1968-01-01
73403 01-Jan-08 1968-01-01

Comment: Could you please post the `SELECT` query that you use to get the data that you've posted? Include all of your `JOIN`s.

Comment: Sure:  Here it is:                    SELECT DISTINCT T_EncounterSurgery.HUN, T_EncounterSurgery.SurgDate, T_EncounterIntervention.InvestigationDate
FROM T_EncounterSurgery INNER JOIN T_EncounterIntervention ON T_EncounterSurgery.HUN = T_EncounterIntervention.HUN
WHERE (((T_EncounterSurgery.SurgDate)<=(SELECT MAX(InvestigationDate) FROM T_EncounterIntervention t WHERE t.HUN = T_EncounterSurgery.HUN)));

Comment: See my new answer below. I do have one question, though. Your question says that for `22-Nov-10` the most recent `InvestigationDate` would be `2011-02-07` but from the data you pasted it looks like it should be `2005-01-22`. Are you sure that your `JOIN` is correct?

Comment: No, the Surgery Date was November 22, 2010. I need to get the most recent date AFTER that when the next Investigation was done.  That would be 2011-02-07. I can only join by one thing, the HUN (Patient ID) in the Surgery table to the HUN in the Investigations table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that aggregating on your patient id and surgery columns will get you what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_EncounterSurgery.HUN, T_EncounterSurgery.SurgDate, MIN(T_EncounterIntervention.InvestigationDate)
FROM T_EncounterSurgery 
INNER JOIN T_EncounterIntervention ON 
    T_EncounterSurgery.HUN = T_EncounterIntervention.HUN 
WHERE (((T_EncounterSurgery.SurgDate)<=(SELECT MAX(InvestigationDate) FROM T_EncounterIntervention t WHERE t.HUN = T_EncounterSurgery.HUN)))
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gr1zzly be4r. But the Surgery Date comes from a Surgery Table and the Investigation Date comes from an Investigations table. They are joined by a column called HUN (aka: Patient ID). You can have more than one surgeries and multiple investigations per surgery.

Answer (score 0):

To get records of the most recent data you can do the following.

```
     $sql = 'select column_name from investigation_tbl order by tbl_field_name desc limit 2 ';
     //you can also get id specific details by passing a patient id by using WHERE in the query .
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Satyapriya Mishra. But the Surgery Date comes from a Surgery Table and the Investigation Date comes from an Investigations table. They are joined by a column called HUN (aka: Patient ID). You can have more than one surgeries and multiple investigations per surgery.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on information provided, here is the script.**

```
CREATE TABLE #Investigation
    (
      HUN INT
    , Surgery_Date DATE
    , Investigation_Date DATE
    );

INSERT  INTO #Investigation
        ( HUN, Surgery_Date, Investigation_Date )
VALUES  ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2005-01-22' )
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2006-03-29' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2007-03-05' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2008-04-01' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2009-06-04' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2009-06-19' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2010-05-21' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2011-02-07' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2011-02-15' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2011-07-19' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2012-06-12' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2012-09-18' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2013-04-04' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2013-10-30' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2014-10-07' )     
,       ( 242424, '11-May-05', '2015-09-09' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2005-01-22' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2006-03-29' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2007-03-05' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2008-04-01' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2009-06-04' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2009-06-19' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2010-05-21' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2011-02-07' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2011-02-15' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2011-07-19' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2012-06-12' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2012-09-18' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2013-04-04' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2013-10-30' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2014-10-07' )     
,       ( 242424, '22-Nov-10', '2015-09-09' );

SELECT  *
FROM    #Investigation;

SELECT  HUN
      , Surgery_Date
      , MAX(Investigation_Date) AS LatestInvestigation
      , MIN(Investigation_Date) AS EarliestInvestigation
FROM    #Investigation
GROUP BY HUN
      , Surgery_Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server supports Common Table Expressions (CTE) than the best way is:

```
;with t as (
select HUN,Surgery_Date,Investigation_Date,
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by hun,Surgery_Date order by  Investigation_Date ) rn
from #Investigation
where Investigation_Date>Surgery_Date
)
select * from t
where rn=1
order by Surgery_Date desc
```

*Note*: Created and tested on MS SQL Server.

Comment: Table definition and data were borrowed from edited version of the question